# Random number generator only adds numbers c++

Tags: c++, random

I'm reading numbers from an interval in my .txt file. Let's just say it looks something like this:

```
parameter[100, 10000]
```

My program reads the parameterMIN and parameterMAX (100 and 10000)
And than I try to random generate numbers in that interval but it only generates the 1st number then it just keep adding +2. I'm using object oriented programming.
. It's weird because for other interval that I have in file it adds +3 and for one interval it works just fine. Any ideas?

```
interval_osvetljenost = inter_osvetMIN + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (inter_osvetMAX - inter_osvetMIN)));
        interval_temperatura = inter_tempMIN + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (inter_tempMAX - inter_tempMIN)));
        interval_vlaznost = inter_vlazMIN + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (inter_vlazMAX - inter_vlazMIN)));
```

Comment: No need to bother with `rand` and custom calculations when you can have [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Did you initialize `rand()`'s generator with a seed via `srand()` before calling `rand()` for the first time? `srand()` should be called once, preferably at program startup, and usually with `time()` as the seed.  Otherwise, don't use `rand()` at all, use [C++-style random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.

Comment: I have added code to text, I don't really understand how this uniformint_distribution works

Comment: yes I have srand funcition because it works on one of my intervals

Comment: @Peter "*I don't really understand how this `uniform_int_distribution` works*" - have a look at the example on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). It generates a random number between 2 numbers.

Comment: Good lecture on how and why `rand` sucks and how to use the better alternatives: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use C's `rand()` in C++](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), use [C++-style random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.  In your case, you can use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to generate a random number between 2 numbers, eg:

```cpp
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()

std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_osvet(inter_osvetMIN, inter_osvetMAX);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_temperatura(inter_tempMIN, inter_tempMAX);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vlaznost(inter_vlazMIN, inter_vlazMAX);
 
interval_osvetljenost = dist_osvet(gen);
interval_temperatura = dist_temperatura(gen);
interval_vlaznost = dist_vlaznost(gen);
```